# dereferencing a XML::Simple hash

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<booklist>
   <book type="technical">
      <author>Book 1 author 1</author>
      <author>Book 1 author 2</author>
      <title>Book 1 title</title>
      <isbn>Book1ISBN</isbn>
   </book>
   <book type="fiction">
      <author>Book 2 author 1</author>
      <author>Book 2 author 2</author>
      <title>Book 2 title</title>
      <isbn>Book2ISBN</isbn>
   </book>
   <book type="technical">
      <author>Book 3 author 1</author>
      <author>Book 3 author 2</author>
      <author>Book 3 author 3</author>
      <title>Book 3 title</title>
      <isbn>Book3ISBN</isbn>
   </book>
</booklist>
```

When i put the file through a dumper - it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use XML::Simple ;
use Data::Dumper ;
my $book = ();

my $booklist = XMLin('book.xml_with_attrib');
print Dumper($booklist);

#foreach $book (@{$booklist->{author}} ) {
#     print $book->{title}  ;
#     print "\n";
#}
```

This is the Dump:

```
/tmp/walt $ /tmp/walt/bookparse_by_attrib.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'book' => [
                    {
                      'isbn' => 'Book1ISBN',
                      'title' => 'Book 1 title',
                      'author' => [
                                  'Book 1 author 1',
                                  'Book 1 author 2'
                                ],
                      'type' => 'technical'
                    },
                    {
                      'isbn' => 'Book2ISBN',
                      'title' => 'Book 2 title',
                      'author' => [
                                  'Book 2 author 1',
                                  'Book 2 author 2'
                                ],
                      'type' => 'fiction'
                    },
                    {
                      'isbn' => 'Book3ISBN',
                      'title' => 'Book 3 title',
                      'author' => [
                                  'Book 3 author 1',
                                  'Book 3 author 2',
                                  'Book 3 author 3'
                                ],
                      'type' => 'technical'
                     }
                   ]
        };
```

However when I try and print out the authors - this is what I get.

```
foreach $book (@{$booklist->{book}} ) {
     print $book->{author}  ;
     print "\n";
}

ARRAY(0x249a140)
ARRAY(0x249a098)
ARRAY(0x2499fc0)
```

How would I print out author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author key is an array ref, you need to dereference those too:

```
foreach my $book ( @{ $booklist->{ book } } ) {
    foreach my $author ( @{ $book->{ author } } ) {
        print "$author\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In that data structure, the author points at an array reference.  Therefore, you'll need to either iterate over the array or just dereference it before printing:

```
foreach $book (@{$booklist->{book}} ) {
     print "@{$book->{author}}\n";
}
```

However, I'd advise you to use a better XML Parsing module than [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple).  This is the advice of the module itself:

> #### STATUS OF THIS MODULE
>
> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) is highly recommended.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options and the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with unexpected results.
>
> Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new features are unlikely to be added.

Currently, if you have a record with only a single author, it will reference a scalar instead of an array.  This can be adjusted with options in `XML::Simple`, but honestly it's not worth the effort.

Instead, I'd recommend using better modules like [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), to avoid inconsistencies in parsing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $data);

for my $book ($xml->findnodes('//book')) {
    my $title = $book->findvalue('title');
    print "Title = '$title'\n";

    for my $author ($book->findnodes('author')) {
        print "   " . $author->textContent() . "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<booklist>
   <book type="technical">
      <author>Book 1 author 1</author>
      <title>Book 1 title</title>
      <isbn>Book1ISBN</isbn>
   </book>
   <book type="fiction">
      <author>Book 2 author 1</author>
      <author>Book 2 author 2</author>
      <title>Book 2 title</title>
      <isbn>Book2ISBN</isbn>
   </book>
   <book type="technical">
      <author>Book 3 author 1</author>
      <author>Book 3 author 2</author>
      <author>Book 3 author 3</author>
      <title>Book 3 title</title>
      <isbn>Book3ISBN</isbn>
   </book>
</booklist>
```

Outputs:

```
Title = 'Book 1 title'
   Book 1 author 1
Title = 'Book 2 title'
   Book 2 author 1
   Book 2 author 2
Title = 'Book 3 title'
   Book 3 author 1
   Book 3 author 2
   Book 3 author 3
```

Comment: I'll delete my answer, +1 for the well explained answer.

Comment: oo wow! I've been saying to stay away from this module for a long time. I had no idea the module was saying this as well now!

Comment: @hwnd - I saw your answer on Friday, and it looked good - I prefered your method because this shop does not have XML::LibXML. And the process to get a new module involves alot of permissinion and tickets with the sysadmins. I have to work with XML::Simple for now - bugs and all.

Comment: @hwnd - feel freel to repost your answer - or feel free to get i touch wiht me at the listed address.